# Disable automatic grammar correction for all sticky notes permanently on Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, sticky-notes

I'm always bored by the automatic grammar correction because I use Italian and English in the same notes, does someone know a way to avoid every time to deselect this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "uncheck" the relevant options from within the `Edit > Spelling and Grammar` menu and then select `Note > Use as Default`, the setting will persist across all notes.